# How to get the value of characters while typing in edit text box in another text box َ?

Tags: android

How can get the values of the characters in a Text box while typing in the edit text box of Android Studio ? For example, if the user writes A in the edit text box, then in the second text box, the value of A should be seen as 20. Similarly, the other characters should be given a specific value.

```
        textView.setText(editText.getText().toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at TextWatcher - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
...
    }
...
};

textView.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Textwatcher and convert like this

```
val codeValue = 'A'.code // 'A' dynamic
textView.setText(codeValue.toString())
```

Comment: Please  gave me an example.

Answer (score 0):

**Use TextWatcher**

```
youredittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable mEdit) 
        {
            text = mEdit.toString();
           textView.setText(text)
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });
```

Comment: what means by text?

Comment: String variable

Comment: Means any character such as a,b,c etc....

Comment: string variable that save your edit text value

Comment: sorry sir, App crashes when i try.

Comment: you are working with kotlin or java?

Comment: Sir, as I mentioned in my question. When characters are written in the edit text box, their values are automatically displayed in a text box. For example, if A is pressed, then 20, B is pressed, then 30, so on. I am using Java